# My picture is rotated when want to load in imageview

Tags: java, android

In my project I can choose picture or take a picture with camera.
when I want to load it into image view , my picture rotated .
how can I avoid rotating . My image view id costume image view and it is `DraggableImageView` .

here is my code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    btnTakePhoto = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_take_photo);
    btnFromDir = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_from_dir);

    btnTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnFromDir.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.btn_take_photo) {
        MenuActivityHelper.clearCameraTempFile();
        MenuActivityHelper.callCameraApp(this);
    } else if (id == R.id.btn_from_dir) {
        MenuActivityHelper.clearCameraTempFile();
        MenuActivityHelper.callGalleryApp(this);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case vlCameraConstant.CAMERA_REQUEST:
        try {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) return;
            Uri cameraTempUri = MenuActivityHelper.getCameraTempFile(this);
            if (cameraTempUri  != null) {
                Intent editIntent = new Intent(this, EditActivity.class);
                editIntent.setData(cameraTempUri);
                startActivity(editIntent);

            } else {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Can't create file to take picture!");
        }
        break;
    case vlCameraConstant.GALLERY_REQUEST:
        if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            data.setClass(this, EditActivity.class);
            startActivity(data);
        }
        break;
    default:
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

my custom imageview:

```
 public class DraggableImageView extends ImageView {

// some private variable use for detect multi touch
public enum EDITMODE {
    NONE, DRAG, ZOOM, ROTATE
}

private static final String TAG = "Draggable Bitmap";

private boolean mDrawOpacityBackground = false;
private Paint mPaint = new Paint();
private DraggableBitmap mActiveBitmap = null;
private RectF mInnerImageBounds = null;
private Stack<BitmapOperationMap> mOperationStack = new Stack<BitmapOperationMap>();

// list of stamp bitmaps
private List<DraggableBitmap> mOverlayBitmaps;

// constructors
public DraggableImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initMembers();
    this.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
}

public DraggableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initMembers();
    this.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
}

private void initMembers() {
    mOverlayBitmaps = new ArrayList<DraggableBitmap>();
}

// listeners
private OnTouchListener touchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    // to get mode [drag, zoom, rotate]
    private EDITMODE mEditMode = EDITMODE.NONE;

    private float[] mLastEvent;
    private PointF mStart = new PointF();
    private PointF mMid = new PointF();
    private float mOldDistance;
    private float mNewRotation = 0f;
    private float mDist = 0f;

    // this variable use to deal with android odd touch behavior (MOVE -> UP
    // -> MOVE -> UP)
    private boolean touchMoveEndChecker = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        // switch finger events
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
                touchMoveEndChecker = true;
                mDrawOpacityBackground = true;
                int activebmpIdx = getActiveBitmap(event.getX(), event.getY());

                if (activebmpIdx != -1) {
                    mActiveBitmap = mOverlayBitmaps.get(activebmpIdx);
                    rearrangeOverlayList();
                }
                else {
                    mActiveBitmap = null;
                    break;
                }
                mLastEvent = null;
                mEditMode = EDITMODE.DRAG;
                mStart.set(event.getX(), event.getY());

                if (mActiveBitmap != null) {
                    mActiveBitmap.setSavedMatrix(mActiveBitmap.getCurrentMatrix());
                }
                break;

            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN):
                touchMoveEndChecker = false;
                mDrawOpacityBackground = true;
                if (mActiveBitmap != null) {
                    mOldDistance = spacing(event);
                    if (mOldDistance > 10f) {
                        mActiveBitmap.setSavedMatrix(mActiveBitmap.getCurrentMatrix());
                        midPoint(mMid, event);
                        mEditMode = EDITMODE.ZOOM;
                    }

                    mLastEvent = new float[4];
                    mLastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                    mLastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                    mLastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                    mLastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);

                    mDist = rotation(event);
                }
                break;

            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP):
                mEditMode = EDITMODE.NONE;
                break;

            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE):
                touchMoveEndChecker = false;
                mDrawOpacityBackground = true;

                if (mActiveBitmap != null) {
                    if (mEditMode == EDITMODE.DRAG) {
                        mActiveBitmap.setCurrentMatrix(mActiveBitmap.getSavedMatrix());
                        mActiveBitmap.getCurrentMatrix().postTranslate(event.getX() - mStart.x,
                                event.getY() - mStart.y);
                    } else if (mEditMode == EDITMODE.ZOOM && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                        float newDistance = spacing(event);
                        mActiveBitmap.setCurrentMatrix(mActiveBitmap.getSavedMatrix());
                        if (newDistance > 10f) {
                            float scale = newDistance / mOldDistance;
                            mActiveBitmap.getCurrentMatrix()
                                    .postScale(scale, scale, mMid.x, mMid.y);
                        }

                        if (mLastEvent != null) {
                            mNewRotation = rotation(event);
                            float r = mNewRotation - mDist;
                            RectF rec = new RectF(0, 0, mActiveBitmap.mBitmap.getWidth(),
                                    mActiveBitmap.mBitmap.getHeight());
                            mActiveBitmap.getCurrentMatrix().mapRect(rec);
                            mActiveBitmap.getCurrentMatrix().postRotate(r,
                                    rec.left + rec.width() / 2, rec.top + rec.height() / 2);
                        }
                    }

                }

            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
                if (touchMoveEndChecker) { // means 2 continuous ACTION_UP, or
                    // real finger up after moving
                    mDrawOpacityBackground = false;
                    if (mActiveBitmap != null) {
                        // push a map to bitmap and clone of current matrix
                        mOperationStack
                                .push(new BitmapOperationMap(mActiveBitmap, new Matrix(
                                        mActiveBitmap.getCurrentMatrix()),
                                        BitmapOperationMap.OPERATION.ADD));
                        mActiveBitmap.deActivate();
                    }
                }
                touchMoveEndChecker = true;
            default:
                break;
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

};

public void addOverlayBitmap(DraggableBitmap dBitmap, float scale) {
    Matrix marginMtx = new Matrix();

    marginMtx.postTranslate(mInnerImageBounds.left, mInnerImageBounds.top);
    dBitmap.setMarginMatrix(marginMtx);

    Matrix curMtx = new Matrix();
    curMtx.postConcat(marginMtx);

    dBitmap.setCurrentMatrix(curMtx);
    mOperationStack
            .push(new BitmapOperationMap(dBitmap, null, BitmapOperationMap.OPERATION.NEW));
    mOperationStack.push(new BitmapOperationMap(dBitmap, dBitmap.getCurrentMatrix(),
            BitmapOperationMap.OPERATION.ADD));
    mOverlayBitmaps.add(dBitmap);

}

private int getActiveBitmap(float event_x, float event_y) {
    int size = mOverlayBitmaps.size();
    int retidx = -1;
    DraggableBitmap retBmp = null;
    // search for all bitmap to find closest to finger
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        DraggableBitmap dBmp = mOverlayBitmaps.get(i);
        dBmp.deActivate();
        float bmp_x = 0;
        float bmp_y = 0;
        RectF r = new RectF(0, 0, dBmp.mBitmap.getWidth(), dBmp.mBitmap.getHeight());
        Matrix mtx = dBmp.getCurrentMatrix() == null ? dBmp.getMarginMatrix() : dBmp
                .getCurrentMatrix();

        mtx.mapRect(r);
        bmp_x = r.left;
        bmp_y = r.top;

        if (event_x >= bmp_x && event_x < (bmp_x + r.width()) && event_y >= bmp_y
                && event_y < (bmp_y + r.height())) {
            retBmp = dBmp;
            retidx = i;
        }
    }
    if (retBmp != null) {
        if (!retBmp.isTouched()) {
            retBmp.setTouched(true);
        }
        retBmp.activate();
    }
    return retidx;
}

private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

/** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}

private float rotation(MotionEvent event) {
    double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
    double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
    double rad = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);

    return (float) Math.toDegrees(rad);
}

public List<DraggableBitmap> getOverlayList() {
    return mOverlayBitmaps;
}

public void undo() {
    if (!mOperationStack.empty()) {
        BitmapOperationMap prev = mOperationStack.pop();
        if (!mOperationStack.empty()) { // current stack is final operation
            prev = mOperationStack.peek();
        }
        DraggableBitmap bmp = prev.getDraggableBitmap();
        Matrix mtx = prev.getOperationMatrix();

        switch (prev.getOption()) {
            case NEW: // if action is create new, then delete
                mOverlayBitmaps.remove(bmp);
                break;
            case ADD:
                bmp.setCurrentMatrix(mtx);
                break;
            case DELETE: // not implement yet
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { // [TODO] khi xoay man hinh error
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    RectF bitmapRect = getInnerBitmapSize();
    if (bitmapRect == null) return;
    mInnerImageBounds = bitmapRect;
    canvas.clipRect(bitmapRect);

    // loop to draw all bitmap
    Enumeration<DraggableBitmap> e = Collections.enumeration(mOverlayBitmaps);
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        DraggableBitmap dBmp = (DraggableBitmap) e.nextElement();
        if (true) {
            if (dBmp.getCurrentMatrix() != null) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(dBmp.mBitmap, dBmp.getCurrentMatrix(), null);
                RectF r = getStampBounding(dBmp);
                if (mDrawOpacityBackground && dBmp == mActiveBitmap) {
                    mPaint.setColor(0x00000000);
                    mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
                    mPaint.setAlpha(20);
                    canvas.drawRect(r, mPaint);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public RectF getInnerBitmapSize() {
    RectF bitmapRect = new RectF();
    if (this.getDrawable() == null) return null;
    bitmapRect.right = this.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    bitmapRect.bottom = this.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

    Matrix m = this.getImageMatrix();
    m.mapRect(bitmapRect);
    return bitmapRect;
}

private RectF getStampBounding(DraggableBitmap bmp) {
    if (bmp.mBitmap == null) return null;
    RectF r = new RectF(0, 0, bmp.mBitmap.getWidth(), bmp.mBitmap.getHeight());
    bmp.getCurrentMatrix().mapRect(r);
    return r;
}

public void deleteActiveBitmap() {
    if (mActiveBitmap == null) return;
    mOverlayBitmaps.remove(mActiveBitmap);
}

public void flipActiveBitmap() {
    try {
        Matrix flipHorizontalMtx = new Matrix();
        flipHorizontalMtx.setScale(-1, 1);
        flipHorizontalMtx.postTranslate((float) (mActiveBitmap.mBitmap.getWidth()), (float) 0);
        Matrix mtx = mActiveBitmap.getCurrentMatrix();
        mtx.preConcat(flipHorizontalMtx);

        mActiveBitmap.setCurrentMatrix(mtx);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.v(TAG, "active bitmap is null");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v(TAG, "error ocurred");
    }
}

public void rearrangeOverlayList() {
    int idx = mOverlayBitmaps.indexOf(mActiveBitmap);
    mOverlayBitmaps.add(mActiveBitmap);
    mOverlayBitmaps.remove(idx);
}
}
```

and my edit activity that show my picture rotated:

```
   public class EditActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "EditActivity";
private DraggableImageView mImageView;
private Bitmap mRawBitmap;
private int mCurrentTextColor;

ImageButton mButtonAdd;
ImageButton mButtonDelete;
ImageButton mButtonAddText;
ImageButton mButtonFlip;
ImageButton mButtonFinish;
ImageButton mButtonBack;

EditActivityHelper mActivityHelper;

/** listerner **/
EditActivityHelper.popupTextEditListener addtextListener = 
        new EditActivityHelper.popupTextEditListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOkClick(String addText) {
        if (addText.length() == 0) return;
        mActivityHelper.addTextToBitmap(addText, getCurrentTextColor());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelClick() {}
};

/*** default stuffs ***/
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);

    mActivityHelper = new EditActivityHelper(this);

    mImageView = (DraggableImageView) findViewById(R.id.edit_imageview);
    mButtonAdd = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    mButtonDelete = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
    mButtonFlip = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_flip);
    mButtonFinish = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_finish); 
    mButtonBack = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_back);

    mButtonAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButtonDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButtonFlip.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButtonFinish.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButtonBack.setOnClickListener(this);

    Uri selectedImageUri;

    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null && intent.getData() != null) {
        selectedImageUri = intent.getData();
        mActivityHelper.displayPreviewImage(selectedImageUri, this);

    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.btn_add) {
        Intent stampIntent = new Intent(this, StampChooseActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(stampIntent, vlCameraConstant.STAMP_REQUEST);
    } else if (id == R.id.btn_flip) {
        mActivityHelper.flipActiveBitmap();
    } else if (id == R.id.btn_finish) {
        Bitmap bmpToSave = mActivityHelper.saveCurrentBitmap();
        this.getBaseApplication().setRawBitmap(bmpToSave);
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(this, ShareActivity.class);
        startActivity(shareIntent);
    } else if (id == R.id.btn_delete){
        getImageView().deleteActiveBitmap();
        getImageView().invalidate();
    } else if (id == R.id.btn_back) {
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case vlCameraConstant.STAMP_REQUEST:
        try {
            if (resultCode == vlCameraConstant.RESULT_CODE_ADDBITMAP) {
                DraggableBitmap stamp = new DraggableBitmap((Bitmap)   data.getExtras().get("data"));           
                getImageView().addOverlayBitmap(stamp, (float)1.0);
                getImageView().invalidate();
            } else if (resultCode == vlCameraConstant.RESULT_CODE_ADDTEXT) {
                int color = (Integer) data.getExtras().get("color");
                setCurrentTextColor(color);
                mActivityHelper.popupTextEdit(addtextListener);
            }
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v(TAG, "get extras error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    default:
        break;
    }
}

/*** get/set stuffs ***/
public DraggableImageView getImageView() {
    return mImageView;
}

public Bitmap getRawBitmap() {
    return mRawBitmap;
}

public void setRawBitmap(Bitmap mRawBitmap) {
    this.mRawBitmap = mRawBitmap;
}


public int getCurrentTextColor() {
    return mCurrentTextColor;
}

public void setCurrentTextColor(int mCurrentTextColor) {
    this.mCurrentTextColor = mCurrentTextColor;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the orientation of the bitmap using EXIF then rotate your Bitmap,set the rotated bitmap in your Imageview, 
here is the code;

```
public int getOrientation(String imagePath)
{
    ExifInterface exif = null;
    try { 
        exif = new ExifInterface(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
return orientation;
}
    public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int orientation) {

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix(); 
        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                return bitmap;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                matrix.setScale(-1, 1); 
                break; 
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.setRotate(180); 
                break; 
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                matrix.setRotate(180); 
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1); 
                break; 
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
                matrix.setRotate(90); 
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1); 
                break; 
           case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
               matrix.setRotate(90); 
               break; 
           case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
               matrix.setRotate(-90); 
               matrix.postScale(-1, 1); 
               break; 
           case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
               matrix.setRotate(-90); 
               break; 
           default: 
               return bitmap;
        } 
        try { 
            Bitmap bmRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            bitmap.recycle();
            return bmRotated;
        } 
        catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null; 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: before setting the image in your imageview. in your EditActivity class

Comment: In which class you are loading image in Imageview ?

Comment: I think in edit activity. In my edit activity I have my draggable imageview.but i cant find any code to set image

Comment: Dear, Debug you code as I can see you are using Custom DraggableImageView so you should just rotate image before it set in DraggableImageView.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122714/discussion-between-rajendra-and-nsr).

Answer (score 0):

I add your code like this :

my code:

```
   public static Bitmap downSampleBitmap(Uri uri, Activity act, Boolean needRotate) {
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    act.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    Resources r = act.getResources();
    int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            50, r.getDisplayMetrics()); // 50: magic num
    int targetWidth = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int targetHeight = displaymetrics.widthPixels - px;

    Bitmap resizedBitmap = decodeSampledBitmap(uri, targetWidth, targetHeight, act);
    Bitmap returnBitmap = null;
    ExifInterface exif;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(uri.toString());
        int orient = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        rotateBitmap(returnBitmap,orient);

            returnBitmap = returnBitmap == null ? resizedBitmap : returnBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v(TAG, "not found file at downsample");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returnBitmap;
}
```